# Behave in parallel

Tags: windows, selenium-webdriver, python-behave

I try to run behave tests in parallel. For this I use `behave-parallel` lib and demo project `https://github.com/vishalm/behave_parallel_demo`. But OS is Windows 10. After steps from `Read_me` file. I am getting next `Tracebacks`

```
(behave_parallel_demo-master) D:\Python_projects\behave_parallel_demo-master>behave --processes 5 --parallel-element feature
INFO: 0 scenario(s) and 3 feature(s) queued for consideration by 5 workers. Some may be skipped if the -t option was given...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\Lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
    self = load(from_parent)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 1089, in load_newobj
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Users\Andriy_Petrenko\Envs\behave_parallel_demo-master\Scripts\behave.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\andriy_petrenko\envs\behave_parallel_demo-master\lib\site-packages\behave\__main__.py", line 111, in main
    failed = runner.run()
  File "c:\users\andriy_petrenko\envs\behave_parallel_demo-master\lib\site-packages\behave\runner.py", line 561, in run
    return self.run_with_paths()
  File "c:\users\andriy_petrenko\envs\behave_parallel_demo-master\lib\site-packages\behave\runner.py", line 583, in run_with_paths
    return self.run_multiproc()
  File "c:\users\andriy_petrenko\envs\behave_parallel_demo-master\lib\site-packages\behave\runner.py", line 690, in run_multiproc
    p.start()
  File "c:\python27\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 280, in __init__
    to_child.close()
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

What I do wrong or is this OS problem? It looks like that 5 workers were up but 1st problem is that `TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)` and 2nd `IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

Comment: This happened to me as well on Windows 10, but it worked on Linux (tried it on centos)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Behave so not sure whether you are passing the command line correctly but this error means that one of the method is expecting more arguments than you have provided. In this case, it's during creation of `cls` instance:

```
File "c:\python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 1089, in load_newobj
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
```

This looks like some internal class instance so you do not control it directly so make sure you pass enough and correct arguments at command line.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Behave package. it will work.

Answer (score 0):

We have been trying for a long time to implement parallel test executions with behave (which is an amazing framework). Finally, we created our own wrapper on top of Behave, called BehaveX, that not only allow us to execute tests in parallel, but also comes with great reports and some additional features:
https://github.com/hrcorval/behavex

As BehaveX is implemented over the Behave framework, with this wrapper you should be able to replace the "behave" executable by "behavex", and run the tests in parallel using the following commands:

behavex -t @TAG --parallel-processes 4 --parallel-scheme scenario

behavex -t @TAG --parallel-processes 3 --parallel-scheme feature

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).